# How long does it generally take for iOS Remote Push Notifications to arrive on a device?

Tags: ios, push, apple-push-notifications

Once a push notification is sent to a device via APNS, what are normal time ranges that you can expect to see the notification arrive at the device?  In my development setup I seem to be seeing timeframes of hours of delay, which sounds wrong (and may make it very difficult to do any kind of iterative development around receiving and dealing with notificaitons).  But then again, I generally get Facebook and Email notifications long delayed also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of seconds, at the most, depending on the speed of the connection from you to the APNS server.

Comment: OK, I think the service I'm using to interface with APNS was having some OPs troubles, all is well

Comment: @jlarson what service are you using? Azure or Amazon?